# Kubernetes ingress with default config does not work

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a problem with ingress. It just doesn't work. How to understand and find 
what is wrong?

I have kubernetes bare metal.

Installed helm chart

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name ingress --namespace nginx-ingress
```

In the same namespace deployed ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        backend:
          serviceName: efk-kibana
          servicePort: 5601
```

Changed the ingress type of the service from LoadBalancer to NodePort because it was not created otherwise.

After installation

`curl http://example.com – get an answer example page`.

Now all services work for me through NodePort, for example - myweb.com:31555.

In any tutorials does not write that i need to add something to / etc / hosts or something like that.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a baremetal cluster, you're missing a piece of the puzzle.

Ingresses lie behind an ingress controller - you still need to expose that using a service with `Type=LoadBalancer` which isn't possible by default with a cloud provider.

There is however, a solution. [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) is a provider which will allow you to specify IPs for services with type LoadBalancer.

If you deploy this with a [layer 2 configuration](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration) and update your ingress controller deployment, it will work without needing NodePort.

Comment: I understand you correctly? You want to say that I will not be able to deploy the ingress and my cluster without third-party cloud services? But why?
It seems everything is logical. Traffic arrives on port 80 for ingress service, and it uses nginx-ingress-controller to distribute further.

Comment: When you install ingress controller, it usually accessible via service of NodePort or LoadBalancer type. In case of LoadBalancer and if the cluster is on premise, the service will get 30000+ port on the nodes but will stuck in the process of getting external IP forever. MetalLB solve this problem by  "emulating" cloud load balancer for the cluster by issuing IP address from the IP pool pre-defined by admin. External traffic to that IP pool should be routed to the cluster nodes. It is admin responsibility to setup necessary network routes.